# HWIOAuthBundle Google login device_id and device_name for a webapp

Tags: symfony, google-oauth, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I am working on a Symfony2 app. I'm using FOSUserBundle to handle authentication and recently integrated it with FOSUserBundle using this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 .

The problem is:
I can login using the google api on localhost and everything works fine.

However when I try to login on a real server I get:

```
Error: invalid_request

device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://<server_ip>/login/check-google
```

Request details:

```
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
redirect_uri=http://<server_ip>/login/check-google
client_id=<my_id>
```

Google documents don't mention these two parameters. I tried to manually send a request with device_id being a UUID and device_name set to "notes". The response I get this time is:

```
Error: invalid_request

Device info can be set only for native apps.
```

Request details:

```
cookie_policy_enforce=false
response_type=code
device_name=notes
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
redirect_uri=http://<server_ip>/login/check-google
device_id=4b3403665fea6
client_id=<my_id>
```

Now, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Besides localhost, does your clientID, include your server (by IP address)?  cloud.google.com/console

Answer (score 4):

Google will not accept a local (private) IP address when doing Oauth or API calls.  My workaround was to add an entry in my Windows hosts file for the local IP:

`\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
192.168.1.2   fakedomain.com
```

then register it with Google in their dev console.  That appears as a "real" domain to them, but will still resolve in your browser or code to the local IP.  I'm sure a similar approach on Mac or Linux would also work.

Comment: Will this not have security implications? Why does google need a domain in the first place?

Comment: Apparently, they've fixed it by now.

Answer (score 2):

It really looks like your using the wrong flavor of oauth. device_id is used with [Devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices).  I would really expect you to be using the [WebServer](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) flow.  You may need one of the other flows as I don't see enough detail here to judge, but they all can be found at the links.

Comment: Btw - the client library for PHP can be found https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2