# Google OAuth - device_id and device_name are required for private IP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip) page and plenty others, but all propose solution not suitable for me. I have same problem that the one in link I provided.

I am trying to use Google+ API functions, so users can log in to my page with Google account.

When I had redirect_uri to localhost:

```
$client->setRedirectUri("https://localhost/...");
```

everything worked. But then I changed it to local ip 192.168.1.10 and get error (on url https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.10.......)

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> device_id and device_name are required for private IP:

I don't know what should I do. [I use PHP server wrappers.](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
I can not change etc/hosts because I am also trying my code on mobile (Android, IPAD). So, local IP is necessary, to test it on Mobile. I want to avoid setting up a test page on some real server, because testing web page on localhost is the fastest way, when still developing the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot change the hosts file of some of your devices, I guess your best bet is to use a local DNS server to fake a domain, just like you would do with an entry in your /etc/hosts.
This answer should help you with this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64944

If you set your devices to use your computer as nameserver it should be possible to spoof a domain and use this domain for testing oauth2 authentication.

Here is some more information about this error:
http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/12/19/going-beyond-oauth2-byod-in-the-enterprise/

device_id and devive_name are mentioned in the specs as well: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Google does not accept a local (private) IP address when doing Oauth or API calls. Instead, you can add an entry in your Windows hosts file for the local IP: `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
192.168.1.10 fakedomain.com
```

Then use `fakedomain.com` to callback URI in google instead of your local IP address.

Finally browse the service with `http://fakedomain.com`