# How to set up Google OAuth login on an AWS-EC2 instance behind an Apache2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, google-oauth

I'm trying to get Google Login to work für a web application. Though similar questions have been asked no answer to those could help me.

The infrastructure is currently as follows:

- DNS handled by an external service routing the main domain to an Elastic-IP
- AWS-EC2 instance running Apache2 as a load balancer for spring-boot-services and serving web-contant linked to the Elastic-IP
- Several other EC2-instances running spring-boot-services

One of those instances is running the service that is responsible for handling the Google-Login, which is completely handled by Spring.
I configured the service combining some tutorials found in the net. I am able to contact it and I get redirected to Google, but that's where it ends. I get the following error:

> Error 400: invalid_request
> device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://10.0.0.196:8084/login/oauth2/code/google

But nowhere in the Google-documentation I can find "device_id" or "device_name". I have no idea how to handle that.
Maybe I could trick my server to send the requests posing as the official domain, but I don't know how to do that either.

Does anybody know the best practice how to handle that?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045616/google-oauth-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip ?

Comment: Yes, those are completely different cases. I'm not on my local machine, so the issue is not to trick my PC into contacting itself via a (Fake-)Domain

Comment: Could you provide more details on the config of the callback? You mentioned that _I get redirected to Google_ , so do you get a proper google login page and then when you click login, you get this error?

Comment: I am using spring-boot and spring-security to handle the login, so I do not config the callbak myself. I rely on Spring to handle that part correctly. The rediredt is triggered somewhere inside spring-security. Basically you just hand over the client-ID and the secret and let it do its magic.