# Google sign in website Error : Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google login in my website ..

I am following this example:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

I generated client id for my project and replaced it in above code, I keep getting this error:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> **Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.**

Comment: What is your domain?

Answer (score 41):

I ran into this issue while doing local development. Make sure when running your project locally that you launch "http://localhost" rather than "http://127.0.0.1", "http://0.0.0.0", etc...

Comment: it happens to me as well. Switch to localhost and can work well now.Thank you for this tip

Comment: Same here. I switched to "localhost" from "0.0.0.0" and it worked.

Comment: if you want to access it from local network (eg. from your iphone or ipad) you might check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip/30068100#30068100

Comment: I was using browser based web authentication. So in addition to running project via 'http://localhost:port_number" I also had to add 'http://localhost:port_number' in the developer console under 'API and Services' -> 'Credentials' -> 'Client Id for Web Application' -> 'Authorised Javascript Origins' (port_number : is your port number where your local server is running)

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to the developer console, to the project which was using the analytics api, and then I had to add localhost:port to **both** the "authorized Javascript origins" and the "authorized redirect URIs". In my scenario I was using port 9002
[image: How to]

Comment: For the "Authorized redirect URIs," if I do what you did here, I will get an error saying "Invalid Redirect: http://localhost:9002 must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)."

Comment: Apparently this combination of redirects & authorizaed JS urls works for me, take in mind that there is a (undefined) delay after set the new domains (localhost, development, production). It's so annoying but the documentations from Google are not too well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents. I am on a local developer machine behind Browsersync proxy. I could only make it work using the non-proxied localhost name defined in `etc/hosts` file like this:
`127.0.0.1 my-site.localhost`.

Then I put 
`http://my-site.localhost` into 'Authorized Javascript origins' field and `http://localhost` into 'Authorized request URIs' one.

Then the error disappeared and authorization worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using actual IP address(http://your IP address:8080/) for redirect URL, then it would throw this error. Google auth API only accept domain name as(www.mydomain.com) redirect URL.

Comment: if you want to access it from local network (eg. from your iphone or ipad) you might check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip/30068100#30068100)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following dns name `localtest.me` for local development.