# Not a valid origin for the client: url has not been whitelisted for client ID for localhost NOT 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

Before you mark this as duplicate, my questions is *not* the same as [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh) or [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041418/google-sign-in-website-error-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-targ) but rather a mixture of both.

As soon as I opened my `:/5500` I got:
Google Calendar API Quickstart

```
{
  "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:5500 has not been whitelisted for client ID 311....idvc2n.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

even though, I have the URL in my OAuth 2.0 project which holds both `/5000` and `/5500` ports (p.s. I use the API key from API key and Client ID from OAuth2.0 ClientIDs).

However, as soon as I tried SO clearing cache per [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh) recommendation it worked for `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` only and not `localhost:5500/`. When I proceeded with clicking Authorized, I got:

```
Error 400: invalid_request
Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
```

Which the [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041418/google-sign-in-website-error-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-targ) answer is to use `localhost` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` which if I do I'll run into to the first problem loop.

My code is from [js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js). I have also tried enabling Google Plus and Google analytics API per SO1 recommendation.

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case, I had to create a new key specifying the origin values from the start. For some reason, editing the values did not worked at all.

Comment: Does @Morfinismo's comment suggestion help with this?

Comment: Sorry, no unfortunate it didn't :(

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your authorised JS origins and redirect URIs for the Oauth client credentials? Remember to sanitise any personal information, if any exists.